# DDEX Api Question for Python... Signing ETH Transactions?

Tags: private-key, web3.py, signature, python, external-api

Having an issue with signing a message for the [DDEX api](https://docs.ddex.io/#authentication)... I'm trying to do it in python, and for some reason my signature is off by two characters. Here's my code using the private key and UTC timestamp in the docs.

```
import web3
from eth_keys import keys
from web3.auto import w3
from eth_utils import decode_hex
from eth_account.messages import encode_defunct
private_key_0 = "0xe4abcbf75d38cf61c4fde0ade1148f90376616f5233b7c1fef2a78c5992a9a50"


# Testing the Auth function...
epoch_time = "1524088776656"
message = "HYDRO-AUTHENTICATION@1524088776656"

message_bytes = ''.join(hex(ord(c)) for c in message)
message_hex = b'{message_bytes}'.hex()


priv_key_bytes = decode_hex(private_key_0)
priv_key = keys.PrivateKey(priv_key_bytes)
pub_key = priv_key.public_key

public_address_0 = pub_key.to_checksum_address()
print("PUBLIC KEY: " + public_address_0)
print("PRIVATE KEY: " +private_key_0)

# print("Message hex: " +message_hex)
msg = encode_defunct(text=message.rstrip())
signed_message = w3.eth.account.sign_message(msg,private_key=private_key_0)


print("SIGNED MESSAGE")
print(signed_message)
sig = signed_message['signature']

# test should be:
# 0x603efd7241bfb6c61f4330facee0f7027d98e030ef241ad03a372638c317859a50620dacee177b771ce05812770a637c4c7395da0042c94250f86fb52472f93500 
# but is: 
# 0x603efd7241bfb6c61f4330facee0f7027d98e030ef241ad03a372638c317859a50620dacee177b771ce05812770a637c4c7395da0042c94250f86fb52472f9351b
test = str(sig.hex())

header = str(public_address_0) + "#" + message + "#" + test 

print(header)
```

I've gotten here because I was getting an "unauthorized" error from the DDEX api when I've been trying with my own private key. I figure it has to be something to do with the signature function, but can't quite figure it out... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ethereum expects the `v` component of a signature (the last byte) to be 27 or 28, rather than 0 or 1. You can just add 27 (0x1b) to that last byte.

Comment: I see! Thanks a bunch, for those who may have similar issues with python I used
    `
    yumBites = bytes.fromhex(str(sig.hex())[2:]) # get rid of 0x

    holdBites = yumBites[:-1]
    endBites = yumBites[-1] + 27

    finalBites = holdBites + bytes(endBites)
    finalFinal = finalBites[:-53]`